# Show that the image of the given function is convex

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, differential-topology, nonlinear-system, convex-geometry

Define a function $f: [-b,b]^d\mapsto \mathbb{R}^d (d>1)$  by
$$ f(x)=\int_{[-a, a]^d} \frac{u}{1 + \exp(u^\top x)}du $$
Can we show that the image of $f$ is a convex set? I did some simulations and it seems the property holds, but I cannot prove it or find any solution in the literature.

The following picture shows the image of $f$ on a discrete grid over $[-10,10]^2$ where the integration is over $[-10,10]^2$ as well (i.e., a = b = 10).

[image]

The following image shows the image of $f$ on a discrete grid (finer than the previous one) over $[-10,10]^2$ where the integration is over $[-1,1]^2$(i.e., a = 1, b = 10).

[image]

By the result in [Convexity of Nonlinear Image of a Small Ball with Applications to Optimization](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1011287523150), we can show that the image of $f$ over any small neighbor area is convex, but what I want is a global property.

I think since the integrant is a smooth and nicely-behaved function, there might be some existing results that contain the property I want, but I cannot find any. I have verified that $f$ is not convex, so it seems that results in convex analysis won't help here.

To give you more information, we can prove some property of $f$ by some elementary calculus, e.g., we can show the property shown by the following figure, where the value indicates the first coordinate $x_1$ of $x$ and the curve is the image of $f$ over $\{x_1\}\times [-b, b]$. But I didn't see how to use such property to show the global image is convex.

[image]

Any help or discussion would be appreciated!

Comment: Not super related to the actual OP's question, but I think I can describe the shape of $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$ when $d=2$. It is bounded by the four parabolas: $$ \pm \frac{x}{a^3} = 1 - \frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{y}{a^3}\right)^2, \qquad \pm\frac{y}{a^3} = 1 - \frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{x}{a^3}\right)^2. $$ So, at least $f(\mathbb{R}^2)=\lim_{b\to\infty}f([-b,b]^2)$ is convex.