# Image of the gradient field of a smooth function is a convex set

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, differential-topology, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Suppose I have a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^d\mapsto \mathbb{R}$. The image of the gradient filed of $f$ is defined as
$$V = \{v\in \mathbb{R}^d:\exists x, s.t. \nabla f(x) = v\}.$$
Are there some general theory or technical tools that we can use to prove that $V$ is a convex set? I have searched a lot but didn't find any. Any comments would be appreciated!

I asked a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4430727/show-that-the-image-of-the-given-function-is-convex), which is equivalent to the case for a special $f$.